# Errorbars and bar plots having different positions in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a dataframe df

```
> df
   id zone      mean   SE
1   1    1 0.9378712 0.10
2   1    2 2.4830645 0.09
3   1    3 0.7191759 0.09
4   1    4 1.3030844 0.09
5   1    5 1.2497096 0.11
6   1    6 0.7247015 0.15
7   1    7 0.1776825 0.16
8   1    8 1.4755258 0.13
9   1    9 1.0902742 0.16
10  1   10 0.2679057 0.08
11  1   12 0.7677998 0.09
12  2    1 1.2728942 0.14
13  2    2 1.3189574 0.07
14  2    3 1.0934750 0.14
15  2    4 1.3024298 0.10
16  2    5 1.3029797 0.11
17  2    6 1.0878356 0.12
18  2    7 0.5390098 0.12
19  2    8 1.2761170 0.09
20  2    9 1.1395524 0.12
21  2   10 0.6863418 0.14
22  2   12 1.1534048 0.12
23  3    1 1.2963668 0.14
24  3    2 1.3032349 0.07
25  3    3 1.1302980 0.14
26  3    4 1.3049038 0.10
27  3    5 1.3221782 0.11
28  3    6 1.0464710 0.14
29  3    7 0.4997006 0.13
30  3    8 1.2777002 0.09
31  3    9 1.1480874 0.12
32  3   10 0.6844529 0.15
33  3   12 1.1593346 0.13
34  4    1 1.2819611 0.14
35  4    2 1.4276992 0.07
36  4    3 1.1061886 0.14
37  4    4 1.3572913 0.11
38  4    5 1.3588146 0.12
39  4    6 1.1318426 0.14
40  4    7 0.5321167 0.12
41  4    8 1.3701237 0.10
42  4    9 1.1996266 0.13
43  4   10 0.6977050 0.14
44  4   12 1.2620727 0.14
```

Now it can be seen in zones that there is no 11 number, after 10 it comes 12.
So when I plot it automatically it comes like this

```
axis_labels <- c("first","second","third","fourth","fifth","sixth","seventh","eigth","ninth","tenth","eleventh")
axis_labels <- setNames(axis_labels, 1:11)



ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(zone), y=mean, fill = id)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("1" = "M", "2" = "I","3" = "Mi","4"="C"))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = axis_labels) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.line.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(rep(0, 5), "pt"))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=zone, ymin=mean-SE, ymax=mean+SE), width=0.4, position = position_dodge(.9))+
  theme_bw()
```

So the  bars at eleventh  that are read are actually the twelveth zone in the dataframe but the errorbars are in the actual twelfth place. How can  solve this problem without changing the whole code?

Comment: Your `zone` ranges from 1-12 but your `axis_labels` only has 11 elements, is that intentional? Further, when I try your code, I get `object 'gp' not found` and, if I omit `ylab(gp)`, I get `Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale`. Please update/fix your question/data/code.

Comment: (I'm guessing the error about discrete/continuous is because your `id` is string, whereas the sample data you've provided here is not clearly string. Especially when a `character` field appears to be all numbers, it is generally best to provide sample data via `dput(.)`, as it removes this ambiguity.)

Comment: Ultimately, I suspect that if you replace your `df$zone` of `12` with `11`, it will plot correctly. However, since you expect `zone` to be a `factor` (only used in one of the two places you specify it, they need to be all `factor` or none of them), your plotting will be mis-ordered.

Comment: Just wondering, How can I replace 12 with 11 in the df$zone? I can give it a try

Comment: Many many ways. `ifelse` and `replace` are likely the simplest and will work with strings or numbers; `pmin` would work too, assuming you have nothing above 11 planned.

Comment: Or just `df$zone[df$zone == "12"] <- "11"` (assuming strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes down to a few things:

1. Up front, I'll make inferences about column `class`: I'm fairly confident that `id` should be `character`, but I'm not certain about `zone`. I'll guess `character` for now.
2. You use `factor(zone)` in one aesthetic and `zone` in another; either all of them should be `factor`, or none, otherwise you are confusing `ggplot2` (and me).
3. You have `12` in your `zone` but your labels say `eleventh`, not sure if that's a typo or something else.

I think the fixes are to make a "proper" factor variable.

```r
df$zone <- as.character(df$zone) # just in case
axis_labels <- setNames(axis_labels, c(1:10,12)) # no 11s in your data, no 12s in your labels
df$zone2 <- factor(axis_labels[df$zone], levels = axis_labels)

ggplot(df, aes(x=zone2, y=mean, fill = id)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("1" = "M", "2" = "I","3" = "Mi","4"="C"))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = axis_labels) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.line.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(rep(0, 5), "pt"))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=zone2, ymin=mean-SE, ymax=mean+SE), width=0.4, position = position_dodge(.9))+
  theme_bw()
```

[image: corrected errorbars]

---

Data:

```r
df <- structure(list(id = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4"), zone = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "12", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "12", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "12", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "12"), mean = c(0.9378712, 2.4830645, 0.7191759, 1.3030844, 1.2497096, 0.7247015, 0.1776825, 1.4755258, 1.0902742, 0.2679057, 0.7677998, 1.2728942, 1.3189574, 1.093475, 1.3024298, 1.3029797, 1.0878356, 0.5390098, 1.276117, 1.1395524, 0.6863418, 1.1534048, 1.2963668, 1.3032349, 1.130298, 1.3049038, 1.3221782, 1.046471, 0.4997006, 1.2777002, 1.1480874, 0.6844529, 1.1593346, 1.2819611, 1.4276992, 1.1061886, 1.3572913, 1.3588146, 1.1318426, 0.5321167, 1.3701237, 1.1996266, 0.697705, 1.2620727), SE = c(0.1, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.11, 0.15, 0.16, 0.13, 0.16, 0.08, 0.09, 0.14, 0.07, 0.14, 0.1, 0.11, 0.12, 0.12, 0.09, 0.12, 0.14, 0.12, 0.14, 0.07, 0.14, 0.1, 0.11, 0.14, 0.13, 0.09, 0.12, 0.15, 0.13, 0.14, 0.07, 0.14, 0.11, 0.12, 0.14, 0.12, 0.1, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44"))
```

Comment: One key takeaway (imo) is that if you expect something to be a `factor` in ggplot, this means a few things: (1) you expect discrete; (2) often, you expect *your* order, not lexicographic order as ggplot will otherwise force; (3) perhaps programmatic determination order of the levels. From all of those three, it is often best/easiest to manage the `factor`ization outside of `ggplot(.)` to reduce the risk of forgetting or mis-assigning levels. (For instance, if you do it in the call, you need `factor(., levels=)` *for each use*, easier to update one and not the other. Maintainability is key.)

Comment: How can the the first, second third in x axis be changed  to lets say "treatment "non" "control"...and so on.

Comment: Do you mean in place of `"first"`, `"second"`, etc?